# Package Functions Not Evaluated

Tags: packages, contexts

Edit:  To address the issue raised by MarcoB, I did the following:

1. Added a new global variable gblCopperCoin to the dispatchtables.mx file
2. Created a very simple new package function

```
TestFunction:=Print[gblCopperCoin];
```

3. Exposed TestFunction in the public area of the package.  So it now reads:

   BeginPackage["MyPackage`"];

   MyPackage::Usage="My package";
   RunProgram::Usage="Sets up and runs the main routine";

   TestFunction::Usage = "Print an image of a copper coin";

   Get["dispatchtables.mx"];

   Begin["Private`"]

   TestFunction:=Print[gblCopperCoin];

   ....various other private functions ....

   End[]

   EndPackage[]

I save and close the updated package, open a new notebook, load the package verify that gblCopperCoin and testFunction are in the MyPackage` context and run TestFunction:

```
<<MyPackage`
TestFunction[]
```

Once again, MMA just returns the function name, without evaluating it, presumably because it doesn't know about the gblCopperCoin variable.

If I now re-open the package and evaluate all the cells, then TestFunction works and produces the gblCopperCoin image:

```
TestFunction[]
```

[image]

------------------  ORIGINAL POST ------------------

I have written a package MyPackage which has only one function exposed, RunProgram[], which runs the main routine of the package library, calling other functions in the private area of the package:

```
BeginPackage["MyPackage`"];

MyPackage::Usage="My package";
RunProgram::Usage="Sets up and runs the main routine";

Get["dispatchtables.mx"];

Begin["Private`"]

....various private functions ....

End[]

EndPackage[]
```

I load and run the package as follows:

```
    <<MyPackage`
RunProgram[];
```

However, instead of evaluating the RunProgram function, MMA just returns

```
RunProgram[]
```

As expected,

`Context[RunProgram]` is MyPackage`

So then I open the MyPackage.wl package file and notice that all the private functions are unevaluated, in blue.  After I evaluate all cells in the package - keeping the package file open - the RunPackage function now evaluates correctly.

The issue appears to be that I have some global variables (associations that are essentially dispatch tables) on which the private functions depend.  These are read in from a .mx file using the line of code

```
Get["dispatchtables.mx"]
```

which is stored in an initialization cell in the public section of the package.

This appears to work as expected, as all of the global variables appear in the MyPackage context as soon as the package is loaded (I was careful to ensure that the variables were all defined in the MyPackage` context when I DumpSaved them to the dispatchtables.mx file).  The global variables all evaluate correctly.

So it appears that:

1. the global variables are loaded correctly as soon as the package is loaded, as required, and
2. the main function RunProgram is also correctly registered in the MyPackage` context,
   but
3. the RunProgram function won't evaluate because the private functions on which it depends won't evaluate, due to not recognizing the global variables.

What's the best way to resolve this issue?

Comment: You will have to provide more details on the implementation: it's hard to troubleshoot code we can't see. Your conclusion that "the private functions on which it depends won't evaluate, due to not recognizing the global variables" if global variables are loaded correctly as you said. What do you mean here by "recognize"? Have you tried sprinkling debugging `Echo` statements throughout your code to see who sees what? Have you considered passing the dispatch table to the main function, instead of having a main function with no parameters operating on a global variable?

Comment: So I think what is going on is that the global variables are loaded when the package is loaded in the notebook.  But the private functions remain in their unevaluated state, even after the global variables are loaded.  However, if I open the package and evaluate all the cells, then the private functions get re-evaluated after the globals are loaded and so they are ready to go.

Comment: I have updated the post to include a simple test function so you can see exactly what is going on.

Comment: A function being "in blue" does not mean it's unevaluated. It just means the definition isn't in a namespace on `$ContextPath`. The lack of definitions probably has to do with something coming from `dispatchables.mx` as `.mx` files have a completely different loading mechanism than regular packages.

Comment: The easiest thing to check is ``Names["*`RunProgram"]`` to see how many different contexts `RunProgram` is in

Comment: Yes, I should have said Undefined rather than Unevaluated.

Comment: Sorry if the above wasn't clear:   After loading the MyPackage` package, there is one, and only one context in which RunProgram exists:  MyPackage`.  Same holds true for TestFunction.  There are no duplicate versions of these functions in the Global context, or anywhere else.  So it's not an issue of shadow definitions.

Comment: When you write this package, are you doing it in a notebook or plain text file?  If a notebook, are you making sure all the cells containing code have the "Code" cell style?

Comment: Thanks @JasonB. - you identified the issue.  I had copied the code across to the package from a MMA notebook.  The cells in the notebook were in style "Input" and were maintained in that style in the package.  When I converted them to style "Code" everything worked seamlessly.  Would you mind posting your answer so I can upvote and make the solution more visible to other users?  Thanks! Jonathan

Comment: Usage should not be capitalized. For example, TestFunction::Usage should be TestFunction::usage.